# Is there a word for a travel guide specifically for emergency situations?

Tags: single-word-requests

The area I live in sees a lot of tourists. I want to build a mobile app that is kind of a travel guide - but not one that tells you about points of interest and the best restaurants, but one that provides advice when something goes *wrong*.

Like, what to do

- when having an accident
- when getting ripped off in a restaurant or shop
- when encountering a wounded animal
- when losing your ID or passport (consular services nearby, etc.)

So it's a travelling companion that gives advice in times of need, specifically. The marketing proposition is that this app helps you be prepared.

I'm having trouble coming up with a good name for it. It's for the island of Lanzarote, so it should be `Lanzarote <something>`.

What might work here?

Words I've thought about:

- Companion - nice, but a bit generic, no?
- Advisor / Advice - *kind of* works, but a bit generic and maybe doesn't convey the "in times of need" aspect well enough
- Navigator - not really, it's really just there with helpful local info if something goes wrong. There's other products that help you plan your trip, etc. That's not what this is about.
- Helper - not sure

Comment: "Emergency manual", "emergency handbook"?

Comment: "Emergencies: what to do?" (or Emergency situations")  *Yeap! Lanzarote is such a nice place*.

Comment: Good Samaritans R Us!

Comment: Incident Action Plan (IAP) is the US term of art for specific events; so Incident Action Plann**er** would suit your guide.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because naming is explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, many municipalities and government agencies refer to "emergency preparedness":

> [OSHA's](https://www.osha.gov/SLTC/emergencypreparedness/) emergency preparedness page.
>
> The [CDC's](https://emergency.cdc.gov/preparedness/) emergency preparedness page.
>
> The [National Safety Council's](http://www.nsc.org/learn/safety-knowledge/Pages/safety-at-home-emergency-preparedness.aspx) emergency preparedness page

and others.

So a term like "Lanzarote Emergency Preparedness Guide for Travellers" might work well.

EDIT: As a side note, a term to potentially avoid would be "Emergency Resource Guide," which is a book used by emergency responders to identify the placards on vehicles carrying hazardous materials and determine the immediate course of action in the event of spills or fires.